# SQL batch numbers for every 4 records/rows

Tags: sql, sql-server

I have question around how I can best go about creating a batch number for every 4 records, so if the data looks like this - 2 columns without headers

```
A,1000
B,aaaa
C,1111
B,1222
A,1125
B,uuuu
C,1118
B,1875
```

The above will be two batches as 1 batch will contain 4 records.
So the end result I am looking for is this:

```
1,A,1000
1,B,aaaa
1,C,1111
1,B,1222
2,A,1125
2,B,uuuu
2,C,1118
2,B,1875
```

So this next thing I want is basically building on the above but give a number for each resetting after 4 denoted by the second column:

```
1,1,A,1000
1,2,B,aaaa
1,3,C,1111
1,4,B,1222
2,1,A,1125
2,2,B,uuuu
2,3,C,1118
2,4,B,1875
```

Keeping in mind the order is very important  - which means most of the windowing functions I am guessing wouldn't work? The rules are it is always 4 records pertaining to a given account.

Is there another way of doing it in SQL?

Comment: What denotes the order of your 2 columns? I see no way of retaining the same order using those 2 columns and an `ORDER BY`.

Comment: If there's a way to order your data this way it's simply based on ROW_NUMBER and MOD/DIV 4

Comment: Nothing really, its just figures that have no patterns, but its always 4 records relating to one account

Comment: So what 4 they are doesn't matter?

Comment: I have tried row_number() and used identity insert, but need to batch it by every 4 records as its being inserted.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

As it ***appears*** that what groups these values go into doesn't matter, then you can use `ROW_NUMBER` and some integer/modular maths:

```sql
WITH YourTable AS(
    SELECT *
    FROM (VALUES('A','1000'),
                ('B','aaaa'),
                ('C','1111'),
                ('B','1222'),
                ('A','1125'),
                ('B','uuuu'),
                ('C','1118'),
                ('B','1875'))V(Col1,Col2))
SELECT (ROW_NUMBER() OVER (ORDER BY Col1, Col2) -1) / 4 + 1 AS Grp,
       (ROW_NUMBER() OVER (ORDER BY Col1, Col2) -1) % 4 + 1 AS RN,
       Col1,
       Col2
FROM YourTable;
```

---

Edit: It appears that contradictory to when I asked what can be used to retain the order I was told "nothing", inferring it doesn't matter, that the order indeed does. With the sample data we have the order **cannot** be retained; the columns cannot be used in an `ORDER BY` to retain that order.

To acheive the results a 3rd column, with the ordering, will be needed. I simply add a basic incrementing value into the sample data here to demonstrate:

```sql
WITH YourTable AS(
    SELECT *
    FROM (VALUES(1,'A','1000'),
                (2,'B','aaaa'),
                (3,'C','1111'),
                (4,'B','1222'),
                (5,'A','1125'),
                (6,'B','uuuu'),
                (7,'C','1118'),
                (8,'B','1875'))V(ID,Col1,Col2))
SELECT (ROW_NUMBER() OVER (ORDER BY ID) -1) / 4 + 1 AS Grp,
       (ROW_NUMBER() OVER (ORDER BY ID) -1) % 4 + 1 AS RN,
       Col1,
       Col2
FROM YourTable;
```

Comment: Great! I did copy of your query to [db<>fiddle](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=sqlserver_2019&fiddle=b8b8a65253a3046e8f97a58d85a28871). You can use it in your answer ;)

Comment: Almost but keep in mind the original order is vital. It needs to persevered as this will be in a csv to be processed by an application in the original order.

Comment: @abs786123 which is why I asked, in my first [comment](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/64025819/sql-batch-numbers-for-every-4-records-rows/64025962#comment113218133_64025819) this question: *"What denotes the order of your 2 columns? I see no way of retaining the same order using those 2 columns and an `ORDER BY`."* to which you responded with *"Nothing really"*, saying that the order **doesn't** matter. If it *does* why say it "doesn't"? If it matter, then again, *"What denotes the order of your 2 columns?"*?

Comment: If you can't get your rows in the order you posted them in using an `ORDER BY`, @abs786123 , then the order is already lost, and you'll need to reinsert the data adding a column that denotes the order. If you can't do that, that there is no solution that will guarantee the order you want, as only an `ORDER BY` can guarantee that order.#

Comment: Apologies for the misunderstanding, i have only given the sample of the data but the order is import for the rows to be as they are from how I received it. I do not order in the order clause  when i load it from A csv to a table when but is absolutely must to preserve all records in batches of 4 as they are

Comment: Then, as my edit demonstrates, you need a column to denote said order, @abs786123 . If you don't have one, then you'll need to likely completey `TRUNCATE` your table, add an `IDENTITY` property to the table, and then re-`INSERT` the data in the correct order.

Comment: Brilliant - that gives me what i want - thank you Larnu - answered!

Comment: Quick question this will forever retain the rows from the original is that correct? Say there is 100 account which means 4x 100(batches) = giving 400, . They will all be in the correct way? Following the Identity on the table?

Comment: Why would they *not* follow the identity on the table? The ordering is solely on the identity of the table (the only `ORDER BY` is `ORDER BY ID`). Of course, however,the values won't be static if you delete rows.

Comment: Ahh got you, each time i get a new file I can just created the table on the fly and give it an idenitiy insert and it will always work using that rule. The data it self according to system administrator will always be 4 records attributed to an account. So the rules are sound from both side with the Identity as you say. Thank you again